# MongoDB aggregation and projection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Can someone help me with the query for sorting an array by date in ascending order and as well display the cCode? I am able to sort the array and project it but am unable to project the cCode along with bal array,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "_id": {
      "$eq": {
        "a": "NA",
        "b": "HXYZ",
        "c": "12345",
        "d": "AA"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$bal" },
  { "$sort": { "bal.date": 1 }},
  { "$group": {"_id": "$_id",
     "bal": {"$push": "$bal"}}},
  { $project: {
      bal: { $slice: ["$bal",2]} ,"cCode": 1}
  }
])
```

My collection:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "a" : "NA",
        "b" : "HXYZ",
        "c" : "12345",
        "d" : "AA"
    },
    "cCode" : "HHH",

       "bal" : [
     {
            "type" : "E",
            "date" : "2015-08-02"

    },

    {
            "type" : "E",
            "date" : "2015-08-01"


    },
     {
            "type" : "E",
            "date" : "2015-07-07"


    }

 ]
 }
```

Please help me what is the problem in the above query. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cCode` field vanished when you use `$group` stage. So, To get that field again in the pipeline you need to use `$first` aggregation. Something like this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "_id": { "$eq": { "a": "NA", "b": "HXYZ", "c": "12345", "d": "AA" }}
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$bal" },
  { "$sort": { "bal.date": 1 }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "bal": { "$push": "$bal" },
    "cCode": { "$first": "$cCode" }
  }},
  { "$project": { "bal": { "$slice": ["$bal", 2] } ,"cCode": 1 }}
])
```